# Dataextract python library to refresh tableau extracts - alternative

Tags: python, tableau-api

Is there an alternative library to refresh Tableau extracts apart from using dataextract. I have tried to install dataextract and get this error

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dataextract (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for dataextract
```

I am using Anaconda python 3.6

On my tableau server the option to schedule extract via access is not installed. So i am trying it via python.

I also tried it via command prompt as well by downloading the zip file from github.

```
C:\Users\Desktop>pip install tableau-dataextract-api-master.zip
Processing c:\users\desktop\tableau-dataextract-api-master.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-b_o6wmbt\setup.py", line 24
        print 'Python >= 2.6 required'
                                     ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(print 'Python >= 2.6 required')?

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-b_o6wmbt\
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful for an alternative.

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: I may have missed this in your question text, but why isn't setting up a schedule on the server an option?

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't specify which version of Tableau you are running. My answer assumes you are using a version that uses the Hyper engine instead of tde files. If that's not correct, please edit your question.

The python library you are trying to install is for the older tde files. It only works with Python 2.6+, but not Python 3.x.

There is a newer library called Extract API 2.0 which is for manipulating Hyper files. It is compatible with python 3.x.

Installation and download links are available at
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/extract_api/en-us/help.htm#Extract/extract_api_installing.htm.

Comment: I am currently using Tableau 10.3 and the Tableau server is also 10.3. The challenge is that the auto refresh for Access database extracts has not been enabled also the enabling would not be done in the near future.

Comment: In that case, if you are using v10.3, you cannot use python 3.x. The data extract libraries (for tde files) do not support python 3.x.

Comment: Thank you for the information. This will avoid me spending time on the coding piece